# What is the name of this game?

Tags: identify-this-game, playing-cards

I used to play this card game a lot but I haven't in many years and have forgotten nearly everything about the game. All I can remember is that it's a single player card game, you arrange the cards into a triangle with -I may be wrong about this part- the first layer of the triangle with cards face down and the other -or at least next layer- face up. Also, it was played with a standard 52 card deck i think. 
      It may be a japanese game because I lived in japan for a large portion of my life and may have learned it there, and I don't remember where I leaned it.

If anyone has any ideas at to what the name of the game is, please tell me even if it's a guess. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

From Wikipedia's [List of patience (i.e. solitaire) games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_patience_games), there are three that I could find with a triangular layout, plus one with three triangles, that might be the one you're thinking of:

- [Pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(solitaire))
- [Bowling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowling_(solitaire))
- [Tree Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_Solitaire)
- [Tri Peaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tri_Peaks)

I'm going to guess Pyramid, since I believe it's more well-known than Bowling or Tree.

Comment: Probably pyramid